# Using \newcommand to replace options in a command?

Tags: macros, errors

I'm trying to replace a single option (e.g., `width=2mm` or `colour=green` or `dotted`) with a simple `\newcommand`. I`m imagining something short like `\w2`, `\cg`, or `\qst`, just for typing speed (especially with the `option=something` ones).

What I'm specifically trying to do:

```
\usepackage{todonotes}

\newcommand{\q}{color=green}

\todo[\q]{my text goes here}
```

I'm given an error that reads "Package xkeyval Error: `color=green' undefined in families todonotes'.

Now, the package gives an alternative to this, which is to fully write out the whole line as a new command, i.e.:

```
\newcommand{\q}{\todo[color=green]{my text goes here}}
\newcommand{\q}[1]{\todo[color=green]{#1}}
```

Which is not terrible, but now I'm just curious how I can set one option as a command, since I haven't been able to find it anywhere, and I'm sure I'll want to do this in the future.

**Update**
Looks like my speediest version is to do:

```
\newcommand{\q}[2][]{\todo[color=green, #1]{#1}}
```

So I can still change other options as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyval parser goes to some lengths *not* to expand macros so that you can use them in values without them being expanded at the wrong time.

So you could force `\q` to expand before being passed in by

```
 \expandafter\todo\expandafter[\q]
```

But that isn't very convenient,

```
 \newcommand\q{\todo[color=green]}
```

is likely to be the simplest version.

Comment: Simple and speedy was what I was hoping for - this explains why all the other answers I was seeing when looking this up were so complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can define new keys.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newtodooption[2]{%
  \define@key{todonotes}{#1}[]{%
    \setkeys{todonotes}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newtodooption{q}{color=green}

\begin{document}

Abc \todo[q]{text goes here}

Abc \todo[color=green]{text goes here}

\end{document}
```